# Derivative involving inner product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inner-products

How would I take the derivative of a function $$f(x) = \langle x,x \rangle=x^{T}x?$$ The answer seems to be $2x$ but I don't know how to explicitly show this other than saying "there are $2 x$'s being operated on so just take down the power two and we have one $x$ leftover i.e. the power rule". I don't know how to get the derivative of $$x^{T}Ax$$ from this either. Is it just $2Ax$?

Comment: Is this the derivative as in the gradient vector?

Comment: Not actually sure. I'm trying to decipher class notes but it just goes "the derivative is obviously so and so". No one else has an explanation other than "the dimensions match up"

Comment: What is $\;x\;$ ? What's the domain of $\;f\;$ ? What the range?

Comment: $$x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}
  \\x^T\\x=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$$
and so
$$\nabla(\\x^T\\x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(\\x^T\\x)\\e_1+\cdots+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}(\\x^T\\x)\\e_n
  =2x_1\\e_1+\cdots+2x_n\\e_n
  =2\\x\ .$$
It is easy to check in the $2\times2$ case that
$$\nabla(\\x^TA\\x)=(A+A^T)\\x\ ,$$
and if $A$ is symmetric (which may well be the case in this kind of problem) this simplifies to $2A\\x$.  If $n>2$ the same result is true though a bit more intricate to confirm.

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense and is much better than my professor staring at me with an "Are you serious?" look on his face haha

Comment: Glad it helped, but remember this is only correct if the question was regarding the gradient vector - it may possibly have been something different.